# Java ASM override existing class/method at runtime

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

My goal is to convert this class

```
public Class C {
    public static void print(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

into this class, then call the `print()` method with this sequence

```
C.print(1);  // call original method

// Code that overrides existing class  

C.print(2);  // call overridden method
```

as,

```
    public Class C {
        public static void print(int i) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

I have been reading the documentation from http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf but I can't seem to figure how to override an existing class/method. (I want to do everything in memory, I don't want to write the class to disk.) I have been able to dynamically create the class with a class loader, and invoke the changed method with reflection, but I don't understand how to override the existing one.

this has been my attempt so far.

```
import org.objectweb.asm.*;

public class MainClass implements Opcodes {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            // print out original method
            C.print(1);
            // new line to separate calls
            System.out.println();

            // get the bytes i want to inject
            byte[] b1 = CDump.dump();

            // dynamically load the class
            MyClassLoader loader = new MyClassLoader();
            Class<?> myClass = loader.defineClass("C", b1);
            // invoke the method
            myClass.getMethods()[0].invoke(null, new Object[] { 2 });
            // new line to separate calls
            System.out.println();

            // ??? (code that overrides existing class)

            // i want to call the overridden method
            C.print(2);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public Class defineClass(String name, byte[] b) {
        return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
    }

}
```

Code from ASMifier. This contains the edit that i want to preform

```
public class CDump implements Opcodes {

    public static byte[] dump() throws Exception {

        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
        MethodVisitor mv;

        cw.visit(V1_7, ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_SUPER, "C", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

        cw.visitSource("C.java", null);

        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            Label l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(2, l0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V");
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            Label l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("this", "LC;", null, l0, l1, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_STATIC, "print", "(I)V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            Label l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(19, l0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(I)V");
            Label l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLineNumber(20, l1);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(I)V");
            Label l2 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l2);
            mv.visitLineNumber(21, l2);
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            Label l3 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l3);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("i", "I", null, l0, l3, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        cw.visitEnd();

        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean with “overriding” in your question. If you want to replace a class with a modified version, you have to use the [Instrumentation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). Note that this is not supported by all JVMs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answer to this question comes rather late, but I digress.

One of the solutions, as mentioned by the comments, is to use the instrumentation API, and as pointed out, is not supported by some JVMs, and IMHO, is a quick and dirty solution.

Another way is to create your class loader in the main method (for example, `Entry.main`). Then, load the class, which actually will bootstrap the application (for example, `Bootstrap`, with its respective `main` method) from the class loader you just created. All code that is ran in the `Bootstrap` class now should use the class loader you created. Here's a rough example:

```java
// Entry.java

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
    MyClassLoader cl = new MyClassLoader(parent);
    Class<?> bootstrap = cl.loadClass("me.myapp.Bootstrap");
    try {
        Method method = bootstrap.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        method.invoke(null);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // ...
    }
}

// Bootstrap.java

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello from MyClassLoader!");
}
```

The main advantage of this approach is that it will work on virtually all JVMs. However, this comes at the cost of requiring you to actually be in control of the `main` method, which is not possible when you're writting a library.